# Excel VBA: Get list of data in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating an automation to automate some task. Basically, I have this data:

[image]

My goal is to transfer all of the account in another sheet (Sheet2).

Problem: I can't seem to display the bank name along with the account number under them. As the bank name is always blank.

The bank and account number can grow, in this case I wanted it to be dynamic. However, when I tried to add an account number in the last bank it stopped pasting the additional account number. Also if the code can also be improved?

To summarize, I wanted to get the list of account number under a bank. After getting it, I will be doing some other tasks before it loop to another bank and account number. But I haven't yet included in the code below:

```
Sub test1()

Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("B2").Select

For i = 2 To lRow

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = "" Then

            ActiveCell.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Offset(1.1).Select
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select


    Else
        ActiveCell.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(1.1).Select
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        'I need to to insert other steps here
        MsgBox "New Bank. Need to do other steps"

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: I am not able to understand the outcome by reading your code and description. Can you post a snapshot of "desired result" and some sample data to copy and test.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the desired result. This will be in sheet 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try code below. Update sheet references where needed!

```
Public Sub CopyToSecondSheet()
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet: Set wksSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wksDestin As Worksheet: Set wksDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strBankName as String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wksDestin.Range("A1:A" & wksDestin.Range("A" & wksDestin.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Delete xlUp
    For i = 2 To wksSource.Range("B" & wksSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Len(wksSource.Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(strBankName) > 0 Then Msgbox "Finished copying records for : " & strBankName, vbOKOnly
            strBankName = wksSource.Range("A" & i).Value
            wksSource.Range("A" & i).Copy wksDestin.Range("A" & wksDestin.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        wksSource.Range("B" & i).Copy wksDestin.Range("A" & wksDestin.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next
    Msgbox "Update completed!", vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. How about when I need to do something after all the accounts are listed to sheet2 under each bank? As I tried, I inserted a message box after copying "B", it pops every time it list the account number.

Comment: Thank you! But what I meant is, after copying list of account numbers for each bank, it will prompt me that it already copied all account number for that bank before proceeding to another bank. How can I achieve it? Thanks again..

Comment: Hi shrivallabha.redij, thanks again. But sorry to confuse. What I would like to achieve is that, after copying the list of account numbers, it will prompt a message box that account numbers has been copied for the Bank. For example for Bank 1, from 12345 to 12351, after copying to the sheet 2, it will prompt done copying account numbers for Bank 1. And so on..continue to bank 2.. and so on..Thank you.

Comment: @Sevpoint what did you try? SO expects person to put in some efforts. See edited code.

Comment: Hi shrivallabha.redij. Thank you! Sorry as I am only occasionally creating automation and not really well versed. Thank you for the help! It works as expected. :)